# Styling 4 different divs with :hover, :visited and :active

Tags: css, html, styling

I hope someone can help me out with this.

I got this HTML:

```
<a href="http://test"><div id="topleftbox"></div></a>
<a href="http://test"><div id="toprightbox"></div></a>
<a href="http://test"><div id="bottomleftbox"></div></a>
<a href="http://test"><div id="bottomrightbox"></div></a>
```

I style these divs with a background image like this:

```
#topleftbox {
  background: url(../img/images/layout_03.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 229px;
  height: 228px;
  float: left;
  }

 #topleftbox:hover {
  background: url(../img/hoverimages/layout_03.jpg);
  }
```

My hover with the new image works. Is it possible to add :visited and :active so the new (hover) image is permanently showing after clicking/visiting the previous link/image?

Thanks

---

jsfiddle.net/AcvbG - This works now with colors. Strangely not with background images..

My goal is: `When clicking,hovering the #leftbox` the background image has to change to another, using :visited, :hover and :active.

Anyone knows the solution? Or do I have to use javascript (limited knowledge) Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>I don't believe those pseudo-classes will do what you want.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes</del>

> The :active pseudo-class applies while an element is being activated
>   by the user. For example, between the times the user presses the mouse
>   button and releases it.
>
> The :visited pseudo-class applies once the link has been visited by the user.

<del>If you are willing to use javascript, then there are some options.</del>

EDIT:

You could potentially style your `<a>` tags to be like your divs, and just change their background. That is totally doable.

http://jsfiddle.net/AcvbG/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My javascript knowledge is limited but I'm willing to give it a try..

Comment: The above is correct - the pseudo-classes won't do what you're looking for because they simply don't work that way; they have pre-determined roles.  If you go with JS or jQuery, it wouldn't be too hard.

$("a").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("visited");
});

.visited { background: url(../img/hoverimages/layout_03.jpg); }

Comment: @TammyShipps I was too quick to answer, I think it can actually be done with CSS

Comment: @Llepwryd Yes. I tried styling my <a> tags to be my divs. That didnt work for me at first. But I just found out why.. I didnt specify my link in the html (stupid me) Thanks for your answers all! cheers

Comment: Hmm.. strange, it works with the background colors. Not with background images.. Someone knows why?