# How to style a div with background images using pseudoclasses :active :visited :hover?

Tags: html, css, background-image, pseudo-class

I got 4 divs and want to style them like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/AcvbG

HTML:

```
<a href="http://test" id="topleftbox"></a>
```

CSS:

```
#topleftbox {
  background: red;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 229px;
  height: 228px;
  float: left;
  }

 #topleftbox:hover {
  background: blue;
  }

 #topleftbox:active {
  background: green;
  }

 #topleftbox:visited {
  background: yellow;
  }
```

But replace the colors with background images. The :hover works, but :visited and :actived arent taking effect.

Anyone knows the solution? I got limited knowledge in javascript so i hope there is a way to work around this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Styling 4 different divs with :hover, :visited and :active](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15123505/styling-4-different-divs-with-hover-visited-and-active)

Comment: Your code works just fine.

Comment: @Quentin: Is it a repost? It seems more like a follow-up question to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your :visited and :actived pseudo class wont be visible within jsFiddle since the href="http://test".  So, you need to visit the page test to see :visited in action .. AND you need to be on test page to see :active in action.

Here [i made a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AcvbG/3/) for you

You can see where .css differs

```
.topleftbox:hover {
    background: blue;
}
.topleftbox:visited {
    background: yellow;
}
.topleftbox:visited:hover {
    background: pink;
}
.topleftbox:active {
    background: green;
}
```

Also, you should give a check to the ORDER in witch you define your styling.

> a:link    { color: red }    /* unvisited links */
>
> a:visited { color: > blue }   /* visited links   */
>
> a:hover   { color: yellow } /* user hovers */
>
> a:active  { color: lime }   /* active links    */
>
> Note that the A:hover must be placed after the A:link and A:visited
>   rules, since otherwise the cascading rules will hide the 'color'
>   property of the A:hover rule. Similarly, because A:active is placed
>   after A:hover, the active color (lime) will apply when the user both
>   activates and hovers over the A element.
>
> An example of combining dynamic pseudo-classes:
>
> a:focus { background: yellow } a:focus:hover { background: white }
>
> The last selector matches A elements that are in pseudo-class :focus
>   and in pseudo-class :hover.

Comment: active actually works on jsfiddle if you click and hold on the box

Comment: Active is for onlick event.

Comment: @Milche Patern +1 for creative demonstration of his problem. =)

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation! Got most of the stuff working now

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers, CSS can handle what you want without the use of javascript.

http://jsfiddle.net/CWkdY/10/

One thing to notice is that your identifier could benefit from discerning that your ID is a link by adding 'a' in front of your id declaration.  Also your initial definition would benefit from 'display:block'.  Like this:

```
a#topleftbox {
  background: url('http://d241yswl6yg9sc.cloudfront.net/linen-texture2/top-new.jpg');
  width: 229px;
  height: 228px;
  float: left;
  display:block;
  }
```

If you notice your images are initially not showing, try caching all the images you need to use with this little trick.  Where you have a div with all the images, off the the side, but hidden.

http://perishablepress.com/css-image-caching/

Comment: What CSS3 ? I see no CSS3 here.